# Error while implementing MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

Today i got an error while trying to implement MembershipProvider.

```
    Error   1   The type 'System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderBase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

The thing that i have done is i added a reference of system.web because i had to implement membershipProvider which is under System.Web.Security. and now i get this error. thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

When implementing a custom MembershipProvider, you must also put a reference to System.Configuration (as indicated by the exception), because the MembershipProvider gets configured via settings in web.config.